# How do I assign a variable in a function, and then use that variable later?

Tags: python, csv

I'm coding a discord bot to send data from a CSV file, and using functions as I'm new to them. I'm trying to store data from the csv into a variable and then sending it off to Discord. However I get this error every time I try to run it:

```
NameError: name 'row2' is not defined
```

Code:

```py
def fileDeleteion(fileName):
    if os.path.exists(fileName):
        os.remove(fileName)
    else:
        print("The file does not exist")
        
def userIdThing(id):
    print("ID THING")
    with open('data.csv', 'r') as dataFile:
        print("CSV OPEN")
        dataFileReader = csv.reader(dataFile)
        for row in dataFileReader:
            if row[0] == id:
                row2 = int(row[1])
                row4 = int(row[4])
                print(row2, " ", row4)
                #return [row2, row4]
                dataFile.close
                return row2, row4

#global row2
#global row4
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "!graph":
        fileDeleteion("test.png")
        fileDeleteion("id.csv")
        #userID2 = (message.author.id)
        userIdThing(int(message.author.id))
        time.sleep(3)
        #print(userID2)
        #print(row2, " row2 ", row4, " row4")
        plt.plot([0, row2, row4])
        plt.ylabel('Follower Increase')
        plt.xlabel("days")
        #plt.show()
        await message.channel.send(file=discord.File("test.png"))
        fileDeleteion("test.png")
        fileDeleteion("id.csv")
```

This is what the CSV file looks like:

```
User, followers, account, thedate, followerUpdate
399287308274106370,334,mallardofglory,2022-07-23,4
649023485229662240,1263,HotRedGamer87,2022-07-23,1
798674024250081300,276,Stormy21ish,2022-07-23,300
```

Comment: You are returning `row2` in your `userIdThing(id)` function but are not setting any variables equal to it outside of the function. If you do something like `row2, row4 =userIdThing(id)` in your `if` statement then you should be able to use the `row2` variable

Answer (score 0):

If you return something in a function you need to assign the return value to a variable to use it. This code should work:

```py
   def fileDeleteion(fileName):
    if os.path.exists(fileName):
        os.remove(fileName)
    else:
        print("The file does not exist")

def userIdThing(id):
    print("ID THING")
    with open('data.csv', 'r') as dataFile:
        print("CSV OPEN")
        dataFileReader = csv.reader(dataFile)
        for row in dataFileReader:
            if row[0] == id:
                row2 = int(row[1])
                row4 = int(row[4])
                print(row2, " ", row4)
                #return [row2, row4]
                dataFile.close
                return row2, row4

#global row2
#global row4
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "!graph":
        fileDeleteion("test.png")
        fileDeleteion("id.csv")
        #userID2 = (message.author.id)
        row2, row4 = userIdThing(int(message.author.id)) #assigning returned values to variables
        time.sleep(3)
        #print(userID2)
        #print(row2, " row2 ", row4, " row4")
        plt.plot([0, row2, row4])
        plt.ylabel('Follower Increase')
        plt.xlabel("days")
        #plt.show()
        await message.channel.send(file=discord.File("test.png"))
        fileDeleteion("test.png")
        fileDeleteion("id.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

To access variables returned in functions, you must set that variable equal to that function outside of the function. For you code it would be:

```py
def fileDeleteion(fileName):
    if os.path.exists(fileName):
        os.remove(fileName)
    else:
        print("The file does not exist")
def userIdThing(id):
    print("ID THING")
    with open('data.csv', 'r') as dataFile:
        print("CSV OPEN")
        dataFileReader = csv.reader(dataFile)
        for row in dataFileReader:
            if row[0] == id:
                row2 = int(row[1])
                row4 = int(row[4])
                print(row2, " ", row4)
                #return [row2, row4]
                dataFile.close
                return row2, row4

#global row2
#global row4
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "!graph":
        fileDeleteion("test.png")
        fileDeleteion("id.csv")
        #userID2 = (message.author.id)
        row2, row4 = userIdThing(int(message.author.id))
        time.sleep(3)
        #print(userID2)
        #print(row2, " row2 ", row4, " row4")
        plt.plot([0, row2, row4])
        plt.ylabel('Follower Increase')
        plt.xlabel("days")
        #plt.show()
        await message.channel.send(file=discord.File("test.png"))
        fileDeleteion("test.png")
        fileDeleteion("id.csv")
```

~~EDIT~~

For OP's comments on my answer, I'm adding an edit that shows how to return a list of int values from OP's for loop:

```py
def userIdThing(id):
    print("ID THING")
    with open('data.csv', 'r') as dataFile:
        print("CSV OPEN")
        dataFileReader = csv.reader(dataFile)
        row2List, row4List = [], []
        for row in dataFileReader:
            if row[0] == id:
                row2 = int(row[1])
                row4 = int(row[4])
                print(row2, " ", row4)
                #return [row2, row4]
                dataFile.close
                row2List.append(row2)
                row4List.append(row4)
        return row2List, row4List
        
row2List, row4List = userIdThing(int(message.author.id))
```

Comment: I used this, however I get "TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object". I fixed this by putting row2 and row4 into separate lines and giving them both the same function but each returns the variable its assigned but they become equal to "None" when I print them out in a statement at the end.

Comment: That's because of your code. You are doing a for loop for the rows in dataFileReader and the return statement stops your for loop as soon as it is run on the first loop. You must fix your code for it to run properly. The question wasn't "Is my code working how I want it to work" it was "how do I assign a variable in a function and then use that function (should be variable) later?"

Comment: How do I fix the for loop issue? I'm stumped at this point.

Comment: I don't know what you want to do. Is `row2` and `row4` just supposed to be one `int`? Do you want them to be a `list` of `int` values for every time the for loop hits in your if statement? I'm not  a mind reader. It is *your* code. Your question has been answered to this post. If your code is not working how you want it to, then you need to create a new question with new information. Check the edit and see if that helps.